# Update Array values in each iteration

Tags: cuda

I am new in CUDA C coding, my problem is that I need to update values of an array in each iteration ;

Here is a part of my code, the functions used in this code can be whatever, I need just to know how to operate on the new elements of Old_Array in each iteration :
(Old array contains elements from the host )

```
__global__ void MyKernel(int *Old_Array, int *new_Array)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x *  blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int *p1, *p2;
    int Part1[Nbr], Part2[Nbr];

    if (tid < (Nbr / 2)) {

        //split Old_Array
        for (int i = 0; i < NbrCities; i++) {
            Part1[i] = Old_Array[tid * 2 * NbrCities + i];
            Part2[i] = Old_Array[tid * 2 * NbrCities + NbrCities + i];
        }

        p1 = operation(Part1, Part2);
        p2 = operation2(Part1, Part2);

        //replace  the new elements in the narray
        for (int i = 0; i < Nbr; i++) {
            Old_Array[tid * 2 * Nbr + i] = p1[i];
            Old_Array[tid * 2 * Nbr + NbrCities + i] = p2[i];
        }

        //display values of new_Array         
        if (tid == 0)
            CustumPrint(new_Array, Old_Array);
    }
}
```

Here is the kernel call after the memory allocation and the copy  :

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    MyKernel << <blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock >> > (d_array);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

Comment: The kernel call in your question only has one argument. There is no old and new arrays in the host code

Answer (score -2):

This style of execution:

```
for(int j=0;j<4;j++){   
    MyKernel<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_array);              
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();   
}
```

should basically work. In fact you don't even need to use cudaDeviceSynchronize(); since you're using the default stream; each kernel launch is just queued up and will execute sequentially. So you could write this:

```
for(int j=0;j<4;j++){   
    MyKernel<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_array);              
}
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

for the same effect, and the contents of `d_array` would be updated 4 times by 4 kernel launches.

From there it's just a matter of defining your kernel to do whatever specific thing you want it to do. So this would work:

```
__global__ void MyKernel(int *d_array) {
    int tid =  blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    d_array[tid] *= 2;
}
```

Launching this kernel over 4 iterations should multiply all of the array's contents by 2^4. So if you have some iterative algorithm that relies on repeated kernel executions this is certainly one way to do that.